# How to add exact search in a table using jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

hi i am trying to do exact search in jquery datatables

i have a colum status which has two values paid and unpaid

when i type unpaid it shows unpaid records only

but when i type paid it shows both unpaid and paid colums records

what i want is when i type paid it shows only paid records colums not unpiad
and when i type unpaid it shows only unpaid records only

here is my code

I have done many tries but not any solution work out for me

here is my js

```
 $('#table_exports').dataTable( {
        "oSearch": {"bSmart": false}
    } );
```

also tried colums to show upon the search

```
var oTable = $('#table_exports').dataTable();



var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();



oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].sSearch = "^\\s*"+'1'+"\\s*$";
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].bRegex = false;
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].bSmart= false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "oSearch": {"bSmart": false}
        } );
    } )
```

Comment: i have done it as i have also write this in my question that it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you however I found this solution from [Datatables exact word search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207326/datatables-exact-word-search) and it worked for me. Hope it would help you or point you in the right direction?

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().bind('keyup', function() {
  var searchTerm = this.value.toLowerCase(),
      regex = '\\b' + searchTerm + '\\b';
  table.rows().search(regex, true, false).draw();
});
```

just change table in 'table.rows()' to your table name

Hope it helps!